# Applying syntax highlighting to code snippets

Tags: feature-request

I submitted another answer to the question regarding copying layers from one document to another in Photoshop. My solution proposes [using a script to automate the process](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16373/470) which I embedded in the answer.
In fact, all my answers have been around automating the Creative Suite with scripts.

Unfortunately this doesn't have any syntax highlighting applied to it, which might make it easier for others to understand how it works and how they could apply it themselves. I suppose syntax highlighting isn't a major concern on this site, especially if not expecting code based questions and answers, but in this case it would be nice to have.

Comment: While adding syntax highlighting is fairly doable, I question the need for it on this site. I've been working with Graphic Design for over a year now and I rarely see the need for this, though I can appreciate the value. If you all could provide examples of where having syntax highlighting would have improved the question, I'd love to see them.

Comment: Thanks @Aarthi. It's not an urgent request. However, I've noticed more recently that scripting has been suggested as a solution to questions and that the syntax highlighting feature could be add at the same time as when the new site design for graduation is launched. I could compile a list of posts that might apply. Otherwise, for my own posts, I can always include a link to a Github Gist as well as in the post itself.

Comment: Doing so would be a great help! You could leave the list as an answer to this question itself.

Comment: @Aarthi Well there _is_ [tag:indesign-scripting], which seems a _very_ appropriate reason to me

Comment: I asked [a question on main.meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279629/1464829) about this

Answer (score 6):

Agreed. While not a code-based site. It is nice to see syntax coloring where applicable.

Comment: While anwering this question http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49079/batch-convert-svg-to-psd I've realized there is no support for syntax highlighting. Do you see a chance to support it here in the near future?

Answer (score 4):

As far as languages are concerned, I'm pretty sure it's pretty much always going to be one of:

- Javascript for Adobe CS scripting, or explaining how simple javascript interactivity could aid a design (though those probably belong in a linked http://jsbin.com demo, not the answer)
- The GREP regex syntax used in Indesign etc
- HTML and CSS for [web layout design questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-do-we-do-with-html-css-questions-that-are-code-based-but-simple-and-focusse)

That's pretty much all I can think of. *Maybe* there might be a workflow question that involves apple script? But if it's Mac only, it probably belongs at http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Anything else I've missed? I imagine if there's a neat finite list, it's easier to support.

Comment: I would agree that those would probably encompass all that's needed.

Comment: More and more applications support python, would be nice to add it to the list.