# Can we get some code highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

There has been [some discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/514/applying-syntax-highlighting-to-code-snippets) about this before, but it seems we still don't have any code highlighting.

The [illustrator-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustrator-scripting), [indesign-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indesign-scripting) and [photoshop-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-scripting) tags would definitely benefit from some JS code highlighting. HTML and CSS highlighting would be beneficial for a lot of web related questions.

People may argue it isn't needed and won't greatly improve the site, but why *wouldn't* we want it? How does *not* having code highlighting improve the site?

Some questions that would benefit:

- [Is programming a website for mobile first really necessary?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69569/is-programming-a-website-for-mobile-first-really-necessary)
- [Favicon best practices regarding size and format](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26946/favicon-best-practices)
- [Illustrator scripting: place image file if it has same name of illustrator file](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63781/illustrator-javascript-scripting-place-image-file-if-it-has-same-name-of-illust)
- [Convert smart (curly) quotes to dumb (straight) quotes in InDesign using JavaScript](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63682/convert-smart-curly-quotes-to-dumb-straight-quotes-in-indesign-using-javascr)
- [Specify CSS class names on SVG paths using Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33764/specify-css-class-names-on-svg-paths-using-illustrator)
- [Batch convert svg to psd](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49079/batch-convert-svg-to-psd)
- [How to copy layers from one Photoshop document to another?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/how-to-copy-layers-from-one-photoshop-document-to-another/16373#16373)

---

Update: Seems there is no objection to this and general agreement (based on votes at least), so can this happen? Pretty please?

If implementing this is harder than I assume it is (i.e just asking for it), or there is a reason we don't want this—could we have an explanation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm turning this on for you now. Note, there will be instances where syntax highlighting can't infer that highlighting should be used by the tags in use, in which case the moderators can simply link a specific syntax to a specific tag (which can be done on the tag wiki page for that tag).

Hence, if you wanted javascript for the [foo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo) tag, you'd (as a mod) need to head to the [foo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo) tag wiki to map it.

It's enabled on the main and meta site, enjoy!

Comment: Thank you kindly @Tim

Comment: You're quite welcome! Apologies for this taking as long as it did.

Comment: No worries. I had nearly given up hope :-)

Comment: @cai was looking for OB1, as it was his only hope but needed darth vader to assist

Answer (score 18):

Yes please. I have requested this before but they said there was no need. But here is a [few of my posts that would benefit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a18306%20[illustrator-scripting]), if @CAI's list is not enough. Basically we have entire tags of posts that could use this feature.

Comment: That was a few random posts I quickly found.. we could definitely find more if the list isn't long enough!

Comment: I would likely imagine if we had an actual list that may provide more of a reason to have code highlighting.

Answer (score 7):

I've asked the powers at the Galactic Empire to see if we can get an answer wether we can qualify for this or not. I'm in favor but I am biased as I love scripting questions.

Comment: All hail the dark lord

Comment: He's not *my* father, but I went ahead and did it anyway.